# Browsing MariaDB's source code with CLion

Tags: c++, mariadb, clion

I'm attempting to explore MariaDB's source code and thought that the easiest way would be to use a C++ IDE. I used the Bash script `debian/autobake-deb.sh` bundled in MariaDB to compile the project, then opened it with CLion. Unfortunately it looks like a lot of code is not recognized (even though CMake is bundled with CLion) which prevents me from using autocomplete, function references and such in a lot of places.

For instance when I open libmysqld.c :
[image: libmysqld]

There are errors almost every line.

I'm a beginner in C/C++ so I'm not sure what I would have to configure or install to make CLion recognize the symbols better.

edit : Updated screenshot with status bar

Comment: Has CLion finished parsing the project (look at the status bar for an "Updating indices..." background job) ? For a large project it may take a loooong time (10 to 20 minutes)

Comment: Yes, strange thing is that the "Updating indices" and "Building symbols" indeed took a lot of time, but still CLion throws a lot of basic syntax errors (I've updated the screenshot to show the status bar of CLion). Also in the Project view on the left, a lot of directories are grayed out, like if they are ignored or something, and I didn't configure anything like this

Comment: Does it compile successfully from inside CLion?

Comment: Oddly, the file you're viewing is grayed out in the left pane, as if CLion was not considering it part of the project. You should check the compilation flags/macro definitions/etc. to make sure CLion picks it as a project file.

Comment: @goldwin-es I didn't think that I had to compile the project from within CLion since I had already done that from outside the IDE.

Comment: @etienne : Indeed, if I browse to a non-grayed-out file, I see a bunch of errors but far less.
I changed CLion's config to use the external, system default CMake version instead of CLion's bundled one and ran "Build all". The number of errors decreased a lot (makes sense). I still see a lot of strange errors, for example in sql_lex.cc the sql_lex.h include is in grey with the notice "unused import statement". Could CLion and CMake not see the same errors ?